# install debug apk got INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES error

Tags: android

for some reason, I need install apk with debug signature on real device, but only got INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES. but the same apk can be installed on an other device without error. then i tried using virtual device with different sdk. it turns out some can work and others can't.

it there any restriction when install an debug apk? like, the device must be root or something

Comment: I have exactly same issue...debug build works on Lollipop vm while it's not working on v17

Comment: any news on this topic? I have the same problem.